# Destructuring assignment cause error: "unexpected token ="

Tags: javascript, destructuring, unexpected-token

let's say I call use this syntax in es6:

```
let a, b;

{a, b} = { a: 100, b: 300 };
```

the code will run without error;

but let's rewrite is like this:

```
function fn() {
    return { a: 100, b: 200 }
}

let a, b;

{ a, b } = fn();
```

when I run the code above, it says unexpected token "=";
I am a little confused, what is the difference?

Comment: `run the code` where? FF, Chrome, Safari, Edge?!

Comment: it doesn't matter where it runs, you can try any of the enviroment you mentioned

Comment: None of your examples work for me, but if I do instead `var {a, b} = fn()` (note var instead of let) it works (and if I put both in the same line)

Comment: @hellow yes that will work too, see my answer below. let vs. var not making a difference here - having on same line is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add round braces: `({ a, b } = fn());`

**From Mozilla documentation:**

The round braces ( ... ) around the assignment statement is required syntax when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.

`{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.

However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is `var {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @碳60 yes a very good resource indeed. Please accept this answer if you found it helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, when I earned 15 reputations, I will come back and accept your answer!

Comment: @碳60 now you do ;)

Comment: Done! So excited!

Comment: @joknawe sorry, I did not realized that I have to click the accept flag

Comment: FYI - You can also use `let, var, const` without the braces around the entire statement and it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the object assignment in parenthesis

```
({a ,b} = fn());
```

Answer (score -3):

Use a,b instead of {a,b}:

```
let a, b;
a,b = { a: 100, b: 300 };


function fn() {
    return { a: 100, b: 200 }
}

let a, b;
a,b = fn();
```

Comment: it is not, in your solution, a is undefined, and b is { a: 100, b: 200 }, that is not my expectation